# Layout with two tableviews problem

Tags: qt, layout

I have a widget containing two QTableViews in a horizontal layout. I would like them to resize to their preferred size (so that they don't have to show autoscrolls). I also don't want them to grow more than their preferred size and leave empty space to the right if there is any left. It should look like this:

[image]

I've tried to achieve it with a spacer on the right, but the views don't grow because of autoscrolls.

Can you propose any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you want the two QTableViews to resize to their PreferredSize if there is enough space (but no more than thier PreferredSize) and to shrink if there is not enough space. If there is too much space, it should be left empty. Here's an example that does it:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;
    QHBoxLayout *hbox = new QHBoxLayout;
    QWidget *centralw = new QWidget;
    centralw->setLayout(hbox);
    w.setCentralWidget(centralw);

    QTableView *t1 = new QTableView;
    QTableView *t2 = new QTableView;
    // Version one: the preferred size is the maximum size
    // t1->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Preferred));
    // t2->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Preferred));
    // Version two: the preferred size is the only accepted size
    // if you want the widgets not to change their size, change the two previous lines with
    // t1->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed));
    // t2->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed));
    // hbox->addWidget(t1);
    // hbox->addWidget(t2);
    // add a stretch that will fill empty space
    // hbox->addStretch(1);

    // Version three: tables have a minimum and maximum width. They can be shrunk
    // but they try to expand to take the maximum available space up to their maximum
    // width.
    t1->setMinimumWidth(150);
    t1->setMaximumWidth(400);
    t2->setMinimumWidth(100);
    t2->setMaximumWidth(200);
    t1->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding));
    t2->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding));
    hbox->addWidget(t1);
    hbox->addWidget(t2);
    hbox->setStretchFactor(t1, 1);
    hbox->setStretchFactor(t2, 1); // tableviews have the same stretch factor
    hbox->addStretch(0);  // lowest stretch factor

    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work. The problem is, that even with enough space available the QTableView chooses to show horizontal scrollbar instead of growing. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Comment: You can set the minimum and maximum widget width and use the Expanding QSizePolicy to make the widget use as much space as it can up to the maximum width. I'll edit the answer to show how to do that.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot. I can take the width and height from horizontal / vertical header and have a dynamically resizing view.

Answer (score 1):

You can reimplement parent's widget `resizeEvent` function and not to use a layout at all. So when the parent widget is resized you can manually set the sizes of your tables.

The other way you can try is to reimplement `sizeHint` or/and `minimumSizeHint` functions of the QTableView so they return a good for you size.

Also take a look at QSizePolicy - it may be usefull

Comment: Currently I'm trying to find a solution using only standard layout / sizePolicy. I will revert to subclassing if I don't find anything better.